# Swift 3/ iTunesConnect track app sales live

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

As opposed to Google Play Console, I can't find a way to check the amount of app sales being made in real time. I am not a patient person so I'd like to be able to check this information multiple times throughout the day.

At the moment, I track my website's performance with Google Analytics so I can see how many people visit the app's manual compared to the amount of people who did the same thing 7 days ago. However, this value can vary up to 40% while having the same amount of app sales so it's not a very good indicator.

The app is dependent on a very small footprint so including a framework that tracks usage statistics would be overkill. I only need a way to get notified how many people have opened this app today. Have you implemented this somewhere in your own projects? Or is there even a section for that in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Try [Fabric](http://fabric.io) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could log an event with Google Analytics called "App Opened" or something where the label is the [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor). Another option is to create an [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) and store it in `UserDefaults`, and use that as the label.

By checking the number of events with a unique label you could see the amount of installs.

This wouldn't require you to add a new framework or to implement anything else.

Comment: Thanks but how can I use Google Analytics without adding its framework? Open a website in the background?

Comment: My bad, I understood that you were already tracking activity in your app with GA. I don't think there's an API you can use to have Google Analytics without the framework.